# jQuery: Bootstrap timepicker with hh:mm:ss format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, timepicker

I'm looking for a bootstrap timepicker that has a `hh:mm:ss` format. I've search the web but all I can find is a bootstrap timepicker with `hh:mm` format.

Comment: Some timepicker plugins have options that you set to format how the time is display and/or stored as a value.

Comment: well, use this plugin before [jquery.timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) and it works fine but when i started using bootstrap, it still works but only its function and not the interface. it uses `<li>` i think because when i try it on bootstrap, it shows a dot next to the time like it is a `list-style` and not as a `<select>` just like before i use bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ datetimePicker, by setting the format of the `dateTimePicker` to `'hh:mm:ss'`

You have to use - `moment.js` - For more formats, you should check: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

I have created a JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jagtx65n/

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'hh:mm:ss'
   });
});
```

**EDIT**

open when click the input field:

```
$(function(){
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'hh:mm:ss',
    allowInputToggle: true
});

});
```

Comment: how can i open the timepicker in your example? the timepicker won't show wherever i click.

Comment: I can't click the calendar.

Comment: ow! i can click it now. sorry

Comment: is there an option to automatically open the timepicker when i click the textbox?

Comment: You will have to check the documentation: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Comment: Check My Edit: @MarkVincentManjac

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/B4BzK/466/)
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label for="dd" class="sr-only">Time Pick</label>
            <input type="text" id="dd" name="dd" data-format="MM/DD/YYYY"      placeholder="date" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='clear' Value='Clear Date'>
```

JS

```
var Date = $('#dd').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss',
})
$('#clear').click(function () {
    $('#dd').data("DateTimePicker").clear()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi: Here's the part of the code that does the format parsing. As you can see `HH` and `H` are for 12 hour format and for seconds just use `ss` as in your example, but for **minutes** you **have to** use `i` or `ii`

```
setters_order = ['hh', 'h', 'ii', 'i', 'ss', 's', 'yyyy', 'yy', 'M', 'MM', 'm', 'mm', 'D', 'DD', 'd', 'dd', 'H', 'HH', 'p', 'P'],
    setters_map = {
      hh:   function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCHours(v);
      },
      h:    function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCHours(v);
      },
      HH:   function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCHours(v == 12 ? 0 : v);
      },
      H:    function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCHours(v == 12 ? 0 : v);
      },
      ii:   function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCMinutes(v);
      },
      i:    function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCMinutes(v);
      },
      ss:   function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCSeconds(v);
      },
      s:    function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCSeconds(v);
      },
      yyyy: function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCFullYear(v);
      },
      yy:   function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCFullYear(2000 + v);
      },
      m:    function (d, v) {
        v -= 1;
        while (v < 0) v += 12;
        v %= 12;
        d.setUTCMonth(v);
        while (d.getUTCMonth() != v)
          if (isNaN(d.getUTCMonth()))
            return d;
          else
            d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() - 1);
        return d;
      },
      d:    function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCDate(v);
      },
      p:    function (d, v) {
        return d.setUTCHours(v == 1 ? d.getUTCHours() + 12 : d.getUTCHours());
      }
    },
```